# Android manifest error while lauching activity

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest

I am getting the following error when i try to run my app on a phone with Marshmallow.

> a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER

It is working fine on Kitkat. Please help me to resolve it.

Here my manifest xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.Login" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.Register" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".DashboardActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.Dashboard" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".LocationsActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DashLocations" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".KeywordsActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DashKeyword" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SirenActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DashSiren" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity android:name=".Google.AlertActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.Alert" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Google.AlertSingleItem">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.AlertSingle" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Google.GAlertCreate">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GAlertcreate" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Google.GoToptrends">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GoTopTrends" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Google.GoTrendlist_Single">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.Register" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

`

Comment: Provide a stacktrace

Comment: logcat please .

Comment: Are you doing something in SplashScreen that is related to runtime permission for MarshMallow API? Try to change your targetSdkVersion and maxSdkVersion to 19 and check it's working or not.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working after clean and rerun the project. thanks